# How can I update a surf plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I try to simulate a robot motion by using a line, `'o'`, as a robot. I update its motion using `set`. But I have a problem to update the new position and angle of the robot's view angle. I use `surf` as a robot view angle, because I want to show color gradients. Now I have to delete the `surf` plot, and replot it again every time.

How can I update the figure, rather than completely redrawing it every time?
[image]

This is my code:

```matlab
    classdef Robot6<handle
    properties
          velocity = 0;                         
          position = [0 0];
          angle=0;

    end
    methods
        function Runn(obj)
             set( gcf,'WindowKeyPressFcn',  @keyboard_down,'CloseRequestFcn', @close_window, 'WindowKeyReleaseFcn', @keyboard_up)
             set( gca,'color', 'white','xlim', [-100, 100],'ylim', [-100, 100])
             robot=line(obj.position(1), obj.position(2),'marker','o');
             hold(gca,'on')        
              program_on = 1;
     
              while program_on         
                userdataStore=[obj.velocity obj.angle obj.position]
                %pause(0.001);
                
                vel = [userdataStore(1)*cosd(userdataStore(2)),userdataStore(1)*sind(userdataStore(2))];
                pos = userdataStore(3:4);
                new_position = pos + vel;
                if (abs(new_position(1)) > 100 || abs(new_position(2)) > 100)
                    new_position = pos;
                end
                obj.position = new_position;
                
                set(robot, 'XData', new_position(1), 'YData', new_position(2));
                %set(orient,'XData', new_position(1)+2*cos(userdataStore(2)), 'YData', new_position(2)+2*sin(userdataStore(2)));   
                %delete(orient)
                x=[new_position(1) new_position(1)+10*cosd(userdataStore(2))+(10*tand(35)*cosd(90-userdataStore(2))) new_position(1)+10*cosd(userdataStore(2))-(10*tand(35)*cosd(90-userdataStore(2)))];
                y=[new_position(2) new_position(2)+10*sind(userdataStore(2))-10*tand(35)*sind(90-userdataStore(2)) new_position(2)+10*sind(userdataStore(2))+10*tand(35)*sind(90-userdataStore(2))];
                z=[100 0 0];
                xv = linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000);
                yv = linspace(min(y), max(y), 1000);
                [X,Y] = meshgrid(xv, yv);
                Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);
                figure(1)
                orient=surf(X, Y, Z);
                grid off
                %set(gca, 'ZLim',[0 500])
                shading interp
                colormap(jet(80))
                view(2)
                pause(1)
                delete(orient)
                pause(0.00000000001)
        
              end
             delete(gcf);
              
             function close_window(~,~)
                program_on = 0;
             end
             
             function keyboard_down(~, event)
                switch event.Key
                    case 'downarrow'
                        obj.velocity = -5;
                    case 'uparrow'
                        obj.velocity = 5;    
                    case 'leftarrow'
                        obj.angle = obj.angle + 6;
                    case 'rightarrow'
                        obj.angle = obj.angle - 6;
                    otherwise
                        disp('unknown key');
                end
             end
             
            function keyboard_up(~,~)
                obj.velocity = 0;
            end
            
        end
        
    end
end
```

Comment: You can use the [`drawnow`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) function

Comment: Thank you, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that the same way you update your `robot` graphic object. Initialise an empty `surf` object just after you initialise the `robot`, then in the while loop you only update the surface with `set`.

So for your code, just under your lines:

```
robot=line(obj.position(1), obj.position(2),'marker','o');
hold(gca,'on')
```

declare the empty surface object (it will exist but will not apear at this point because it is empty of data point):

```
orient = surf([],[],[]) ;
```

Then in the main while loop, replace the line:

```
orient=surf(X, Y, Z);
```

with this one:

```
set(orient,'XData',X,'YData',Y,'ZData',Z)
```

---

That answers your main question on how to *update* a `surf` plot instead of redrawing it every time. Note that now you are not recreating a plot at every loop, a lot of the `axes` and `figure` properties won't be recalculated at each update, so you can also take all these lines:

```
grid off
%set(gca, 'ZLim',[0 500])
shading interp
colormap(jet(80))
view(2)
```

out of the main loop and place them right after the surface creation. These properties will stay like that and don't need to be set again at each loop iteration.